# How to serialize 64-bit integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, integer

[Datadog Tracing API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=bash#tracing) requires 64-bit integers serialized as JSON numbers.

```
{
  "span_id": 16956440953342013954,
  "trace_id": 13756071592735822010
}
```

How can I create JSON with 64-bit integer numbers using JavaScript?

Comment: I think you have to use Uint8Array and or DataView

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a lot harder than it seems.

Representing big integers in JavaScript can be done using the [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) data type (by suffixing the number with `n`), which is fairly widely supported at this point.

This would make your object look like this:

```
const o = {
  span_id: 16956440953342013954n,
  trace_id: 13756071592735822010n
};
```

The problem presents itself in the JSON serialization, as there is currently no support for the serialization of `BigInt` objects. And when it comes to JSON serialization, your options for customization are very limited:

- The `replacer` function that can be used with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will let you customize the serialization behavior for `BigInt` objects, but will not allow you to serialize them as a raw (unquoted) string.
- For the same reason, implementing the `toJSON()` method on the `BigInt` prototype will also not work.
- Due to the fact that `JSON.stringify()` does not seem to recursively call itself internally, solutions that involve wrapping it in a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) also will not work.

So the only option that I can find is to (at least partially) implement your own JSON serialization mechanism.

This is a *very* poor man's implementation that calls [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt/toString) for object properties that are of type `BigInt`, and delegates to `JSON.stringify()` otherwise:

```js
const o = {
  "span_id": 16956440953342013954n,
  "trace_id": 13756071592735822010n
};

const stringify = (o) => '{'
  + Object.entries(o).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ([
      ...a, 
      `"${k}": ${typeof v === 'bigint' ? v.toString() : JSON.stringify(v)}`
    ])).join(', ')
  + '}';

console.log(stringify(o));
```

Note that the above will not work correctly in a number of cases, most prominently nested objects and arrays. If I were to do this for real-world usage, I would probably base myself on [Douglas Crockford's JSON implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). It should be sufficient to add an additional case around [this line](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/594c8fa5f8e3fb38b0977f1ff8a87e9d709e7db1/json2.js#L276):

```
case "bigint":
  return value.toString();
```

Comment: So weird that a JavaScript Object Notation API is hard to use....from JavaScript. But this is 2020.